# how to get values in checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have 4 checkboxes. I want when I update the page the checkboxes is populating the values from database.

My code is

```
        <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.CheckBox("Any")%> Any  
        <%: Html.CheckBox("Contract")%> Contract  
        <%: Html.CheckBox("PartTime") %>Part Time
        <%: Html.CheckBox("FullTime") %>Full Time
        <%: Html.CheckBox("WorkFromHome") %>Work From Home
        </div>
```

Help me from out this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.

I take Male and Female fields.
                 
        <%: Html.Label("Gender")%>

```
    <div class="editor-field">
    <%var male = Model.Male; %>
    <%var female = Model.Female; %>                
    <%if (male.HasValue == true || female.HasValue==true)
      { %>
    <%:Html.CheckBox("Male")%>Male
    <%:Html.CheckBox("Female")%>Female
    <%} else
      {%>
    <%:Html.CheckBox("Male")%>Male
    <%:Html.CheckBox("Female")%>Female
     <%} %>
```

It retrieves the values correctly and when we want to select new one it shows the new checkbox.Hope you all others are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include details about the data model and the viewdata ?  Make sure that the boolean properties representing these checkboxes in your model, and that the model is refreshed from database values ?